# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'value_counts'while plotting bar plot

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, data-science, bar-chart

I am trying to plot y_train using bar, I am getting the below error. Kindly help me fix it
I am unable to plot this due some error since yesterday.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
X = reviews['Text']
y= reviews['Score'].values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(X,y ,test_size=0.20,stratify=y,random_state=33)
```

checking the shape of split of data

```
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape)
(80000,) (80000,)
(20000,) (20000,)
```

#plot bar graphs of y_train and y_test

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar([1,0],y_train.value_counts().values,color ='green')

 
plt.xlabel("Count")
plt.ylabel("y_train values")
plt.title("Distribution of y_train")
plt.show()
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-62460aedca56> in <module>()
      1 #plot bar graphs of y_train and y_test
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 3 plt.bar(y_train.value_counts().values,color ='green')
      4 
      5 plt.xlabel("Count")

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs with `y = reviews['Score'].values`, according to the documentation it returns a Numpy representation of the DataFrame.

You are trying to call this method on a Numpy type, which is not provided by numpy. The `value_counts` method is supported by Pandas library for DataFrames.

Try to change your code to the following and it might work:
`y = reviews['Score']`

The type of y changed to `pandas.core.series.Series` and you might able to call your following code blocks.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html?highlight=value_counts